# Unused 'is' at end of if expression

Tags: html, django

```
{% if loop.index is even %}
        <tr class="row1">
            <td><a href="/webpage_tracking/report_page?url={{report.url}}&validation={{report.validation}}" target="_blank">{{report.url}}</a></td>
            <td>{{username}}</td>
            <td>{{report.validation}}</td>
            <td>{{report.date}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr class="row2">
            <th class="field-object_id"><a href="/ceeb-admin/ceeb_program/program/{{report.url}}/change/">{{report.url}}</a></th>
            <td>{{username}}</td>
            <td>{{report.validation}}</td>
            <td>{{report.date}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
```

The above is my code and I did what tutorial said but it raised the error at first line and I don't know why.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)?

```
{% if loop.index|divisibleby:"2" %}
```

Or

You can use [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) like this:

```
{% for o in some_list %}
    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```